# Where has HtmlImport annotation gone?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin20

I am trying to include custom icons as described in [this](https://newbedev.com/how-to-include-own-icon-collection-in-vaadin-flow)  post. But I can not find the `@HtmlImport` annotation anymore (Flow V. 20). This annotation was widely used, should it have been replaced I would expect to find at least some documentation.

P.S. I also tried `@StyleSheet("./styles/iconexp-iconset-svg.html")`
bit it complains:

```
Couldn't find route for 'styles/iconexp-iconset-svg.html'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building off of Jouni's, here is an example using `@JsModule`.

(1) Define your iconset in a JavaScript file.

```js
import '@polymer/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg';

const templateElem = document.createElement('template');

templateElem.innerHTML = `
<iron-iconset-svg name="namespace"><svg><defs>
    <g id="iconname">...</g>
    ...
</defs></svg></iron-iconset-svg>
`;

document.head.appendChild(templateElem.content);
```

(2) Import the file in your root layout class.

```java
@JsModule("./icons.js")
public class RootLayout...
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I will try it asap.

Answer (score 8):

Bower was deprecated in favor of npm and HTML Imports in favor of ES modules in Vaadin 14. I don't remember when they were removed, but they are no longer supported in Vaadin 20.

You can check the migration instructions here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/upgrading/v10-13/#migration-steps